# How to simplify $\sum_\limits{i=0}^n \frac {i} {(c-i-1)!}$

Tags: summation, direct-sum

Given some constants $c,n \in \mathbb N_0$ I'd like to find a way to simplify $\sum_\limits{i=0}^n \frac {i} {(c-i-1)!}$ (for $c > n+1$) but I can't find one.

May there is none existing... Or do you have an idea?

Comment: Perhaps you mean $\sum_\limits{i=0}^n \frac {i} {(c-i-1)!}=\sum_\limits{i=0}^n \frac {i} {(n-i+d)!}=\sum_\limits{i=0}^n \frac {n+d-i-d} {(i+d)!}= (n-d)\sum_\limits{i=0}^n \frac {1} {(i+d)!}-\sum_\limits{i=0}^n \frac {1} {(i+d-1)!}$ with $c:=n+1+d$ ?

Comment: How would that help me solving it?

Comment: You have said simplify - it's simpilfied. Addition: $(n-d)\sum_\limits{i=0}^n \frac {1} {(i+d)!}-\sum_\limits{i=0}^n \frac {1} {(i+d-1)!}=$$(n-d-1)\sum_\limits{i=0}^n \frac {1} {(i+d)!}-\frac{1}{(d-1)!}+\frac{1}{(n+d)!}$ . There is no closed form for $\sum_\limits{i=0}^n \frac {1} {(i+d)!}$ .